# SQL Server Column Mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three scenarios that i'd like to handle, with some remapping i'm doing.

Scenario #1
I have Table A

> Column A, Column B
>    1, NULL  
>  2, NULL  
>  3, NULL  
>  4,
>   NULL  
>  5, NULL  
>  6, NULL

How Can I Update Column B such that I begin with the next value of Column A

> Column A, Column B  
>  1, 7  
>  2, 8  
>  3, 9  
>  4, 10  
>   5, 11  
>  6, 12

Scenario #2
I have Table A

> Column A, Column B  
>  1, NULL  
>  1, NULL  
>  2, NULL  
>  2,
>   NULL  
>  3, NULL  
>  3, NULL  
>  3, NULL

How Can I Update Column B such that I begin with the next value of Column A but insuring I only update the values as a group like so

> Column A, Column B  
>  1, 4  
>  1, 4  
>  2, 5  
>  2, 5  
>   3, 6  
>  3, 6  
>  3, 6

Scenario #3
I have Table A that contains gaps in Column A

> Column A, Column B  
>  1, NULL  
>  1, NULL  
>  4, NULL  
>  4,
>   NULL  
>  6, NULL  
>  6, NULL  
>  6, NULL

How Can I Update Column B such that I begin with the next value of Column A but insuring I only update the values as a group like so

> Column A, Column B  
>  1, 7  
>  1, 7  
>  4, 8  
>  4, 8  
>   6, 9  
>  6, 9  
>  6, 9

Can I possibly handle all three of these scenario's in one statement? If so, how?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB
FROM @TableA t1
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT 
     ColumnA, 
     ColumnB = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ColumnA) 
               + 
               (SELECT MAX(columnA) FROM @tableA) 
   FROM @tableA
) t2 ON t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA;
```

Here is the demos for the three scenarios:

- [**SQL Server Column Mapping With the same sql statement- Scenario#1**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84271/sql-server-column-mapping-with-the-same-sql-statement-scenario1).
- [**SQL Server Column Mapping With the same sql statement- Scenario#2**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84272/sql-server-column-mapping-with-the-same-sql-statement-scenario2).
- [**SQL Server Column Mapping With the same sql statement- Scenario#3**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84273/sql-server-column-mapping-with-the-same-sql-statement-scenario3)

Comment: Thankyou! I was trying with Row_Number and Rank to no avail. I hadn't come across dense_rank. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like homework to me, so I'll give you a couple of observations.

1. In all of your cases, you want to start your enumeration at max(columnA)+1
2. What would be the result of `select *, dense_rank() over (order by columnA)` be for all cases?

Answer (score 0):

The queries to give you the output required

```
    select A, maxA + row_number() over (order by A) B
      from test
cross join (select max(a) maxA from test) M;

    select A, maxA + dense_rank() over (order by A) B
      from test
cross join (select max(a) maxA from test) M;
```

References:

1. [DENSE_RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) - returns a ranking with no gaps, allowing duplicates on the same rank
2. [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) - returns a ranking with no gaps, arbitrarily tie-breaking equal values

To turn a SELECT into an UPDATE, the first one looks like this

```
;with tmp as (
    select A, maxA + row_number() over (order by A) newB, B
      from test
cross join (select max(a) maxA from test) M
)
update tmp set B = newB;
```